# Fortran include Error: Can't open included file 'fftw3-mpi.f03'

Tags: gcc, compilation, fortran, gnu-make, fftw

I am trying to compile a fortran program with the gnu make utility. In my program, I define a dependency to the fftw library with `include 'fftw3-mpi.f03'`. When I try to compile it with `make <program_name>`, I get the error `Error: Can't open included file 'fftw3-mpi.f03'` for this particular statement.

I have already tried adding the include directory at runtime as following:

```
make spectral -I/<path_to_my_fftw>/include/
```

where `/<path_to_my_fftw>/include/` contains the missing `fftw3-mpi.f03` file, but I still keep getting the same error.

I have another computer with a preinstalled fftw, and running `make <program_name>` on this computer on the exact same directory works with no problem. The makefile also does not contain any path to this file, and the result of `printenv | grep fftw` is also empty even though the path to fftw on the working computer contains the string `fftw`.

How can I effectively debug this problem to make it work on the other computer with my own fftw installation?

Comment: "compile a fortran program with the cmake compiler" - [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html) is not a compiler, it is configuration tool, which could configure (and build) projects using externally installed compilers. So, do you actually uses CMake (and has a project written in CMake language), or do you erroneously added "cmake" tag?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes it was an error, I meant the gnu-make utility. Thank you for correcting me

Comment: You have corrected the tags, but what about correcting the question post itself? It still uses "cmake" word.

Comment: The `-I`,option should be for the compiler, not make. We'll need to know about your makefile for any specific advice.